# Is [hdc] a good handle, or is it out of context?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

There are currently 84 questions tagged with [hdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdc). Nearly all seem to refer to the C/C++ `HDC` type, defined in the `<Windows.h>` header, which provides a handle to a Windows GDI graphics device context (similar to a "canvas" on other platforms).

However, there is also a [device-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-context) tag, with 94 questions; these also refer to the C/C++ Windows GDI, but there a *few* that relate to other programming languages (C#, Delphi and even Python). There are only two questions with both tags.

Would it make sense to merge these tags? If so, I guess that "hdc" should be made the synonym, as "device-context" is both more descriptive and less language-specific. If not, then I *could* write a short Tag-Wiki for "hdc" - but this would largely repeat or reference that given for "device-context".

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, both [hdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdc) and [device-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-context) could be merged into [gdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdi) (currently 473 questions). This seems far more appropriate, as that is a topic in which some level of expertise can be had. (2 [hdc] and 9 [device-context] questions also have [gdi].) If somebody (one of the commentators?) feels strongly enough in favour of this, then please feel free to suitably modify this post (adding a possible "burninate-request" tag and whatever else is required by "law").

Comment: Is it really worth having a tag for HDC at all instead of using `gdi` or an appropriate tag for the Windows API?

Comment: [tag:winapi] should suffice imho. [tag:hdc] and [tag:device-context] adds nothithing. You can't be expert in hdc, rather expert in winapi.

Comment: @Sinatr That's what I felt when I came across a question tagged HDC. But when I then found the "device-context" tag, I thought I should bring it up here. Maybe I could convert this into a burninate request for *both* tags ...

Comment: Merging into [[tag:gdi]] certainly seems like a compelling option. Someone should try to find a moderator who is a WinAPI expert and *also* isn't too busy with work to do stuff like this.

Comment: @CodyGray What are the rules on doing that 'merge' manually for tags with < 100 questions? For example, I would be happy to start doing just that, if it's allowed. And others who've posted here would presumably be willing to help out.

Comment: I suggest to wait for Hans Passant to give his blessing to this .....

Comment: @AdrianMole I'd rather you didn't start doing manual tag merges...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now done:

[gdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdi) ← [device-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-context)

[gdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdi) ← [hdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdc)

Please put your rants in the comments below.

Comment: I'm gonna tell Hans that you didn't wait for his approval! ‎

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree. Merge both [hdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdc) and [device-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-context) into [gdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdi). You'll want to manually check each [device-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-context) question in case it got used to mean something else. Shouldn't take more than an hour.

Comment: I've accepted your answer on the basis of, "Look, No Hans!" Please don't be offended if I later un-accept should circumstances change! ‎

Comment: @AdrianMole: I'm no export in windows API, but I am an expert in HDC at least. I say we don't need the tag.

Comment: No offence intended, @Joshua!

Comment: Given how these threads are normally so full of puns, I think @AdrianMole wins the prize for today with his *"Look, No Hans!"* comment.